# How to remove compact title from R markdown to latex conversion?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pandoc

I wrote my own titlepage and it is loaded via an include in the R-markdown file. However, this conflicts with the pandoc title. I am trying to find settings in the R markdown yaml header such that pandoc does not insert the following code snipped into the tex-file.

```
% Create subtitle command for use in maketitle
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{
  \posttitle{
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    }
}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2em}
  \title{}
  \pretitle{\vspace{\droptitle}}
  \posttitle{}
  \author{}
  \preauthor{}\postauthor{}
  \date{}
  \predate{}\postdate{}
```

There is no clear indication in the pandoc documents or the r markdown guidelines how to disable the title generation. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** In particular, I am looking for solutions that allow me to keep creating my title page with the `\maketitle` command. That is why I focussed on this particular code snipped that I want to get rid of.

Comment: My guess is you have to use your own pandoc latex template, and replace the title code there with what you posted. See: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates  (and the rmd documentation in case they override those templates)

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a valid option. I really skimmed through the documentation and I think you are right. If you would place this as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: Indeed, adding your own template is the more flexible option; but still consider the answer below from StatnMap as it is quite efficient

Comment: It is an interesting option, but lamentably it is not what I was looking for. I will still try to create my own template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `compact-title: false` in the YAML works.

```
---
title: "This title is not compact"
author: "Test"
date: "2019 May 10"
output: pdf_document
compact-title: false
---
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is the most concise and simplest answer to the problem.

Comment: Hi...Adding a line `compact-title: false` in the yaml header of the rmarkdown file ( `true` or `false`) does not seem to have any effect. The same title is displayed both times. Any catch? @JaschaGrübel could you clarify what exactly did you want?

Comment: The knitr compiler got a few added settings, which now make the title look the same in the standard case but the particular calls were clashing with what I did at the time. Note that if you set knitr to keep the latex file you can verify that with the compact-title: false, the code snippet I refer to in the question is not generated and the standard-maketitle is used.

Answer (score 6):

I also use my own title page with rmarkdown documents for latex/pdf outputs. To remove the title, you can add the following command in a text file called with `in_header` :

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax}
```

A reproductible example with the `header.tex` file built directly within the Rmd document:

````
---
title: "RMarkdown No title Test"
author: "StatnMap"
date: "July 30, 2017"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
--- 

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r rm_title_page, echo=FALSE}
head <- cat('
\\AtBeginDocument{\\let\\maketitle\\relax}
', file = "header.tex")

```

# Title 1
**Some text**

# Title 2
**Some text**
````

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is not quite what I was looking for. In particular, I am still using the `\maketitle` to generate my title, so `\relax` as a substitute does not work for me. I will update the question, to reflect this detail.

Comment: Why don't you create a new command to call your title like `\newcommand*{\mytitle}{\begingroup .... \endgroup}`? So that you can call it with `\mytitle` in the `before_body` tex file instead of `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. Here's what I did. (Maybe I'll update the solution when I come up with something better.)

The solution is dumb but useful. I can't set an arbitrary space between the lines now, because I used `\newline`.

```
---
title: "\\huge My Smart Title"
author: "\\newline \\Large My Smart Author"
date: "\\newline \\Large 2018-12-25"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
---
```

Below are the outputs before and after the solution.

BEFORE: 
[image]

AFTER: 
[image]

Note: 
  You may be confused about the different sizes of the "author" and the "date" in the two pictures above, if you don't know that the fontsize of the "author" and the "date" is `\large` instead of `\Large` by default.

END